# Custom options clearing out during product save

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, magento1.9.3

We are experiencing a very strange issue with a Magento 1.9.3 site that I have never seen before.

The gist of it is: All required drop-down custom options on simple products are getting cleared out on a somewhat regular basis.

- Already ruled out automated imports and other automation
- Already ruled out dev scripts on the site
- The site is scanned regularly and has a WAF in front of it for access – so unlikely that we are dealing with malicious actors
- It seems to be somewhat related to product adding/editing in the admin

When it happens – the SKU column in the custom option line has the most recent product SKU for all items and the name column is blanked out.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any product related extension you're using ?
If not then have you checked in Database for it. Is record related to custom options available there or that's getting deleted either. if it is not in database then something is wrong with your core files ( of you can dig it then good ) otherwise try to replace them with default.

Comment: We ultimately found that we had a misbehaving extension. We updated the extension and cleared the issue up.